# Airflow:2.3.0:Cannot import name 'STATE_COLORS' from 'airflow.settings'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

**Requirement**: To run Redshift multiple SQL statements in SQL file. So for this to run, the latest provider `apache-airflow-providers-amazon==5.0.0` is required . So have change in the dockercompose as below

```
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: 'apache-airflow-providers-amazon==5.0.0 apache-airflow-providers-ftp==2.0.1 apache-airflow-providers-http==2.0.1 apache-airflow-providers-imap==2.0.1 apache-airflow-providers-sqlite==2.1.0 crypto==1.4.1 watchtower==2.0.1 apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==2.5.0 apache-airflow-providers-mysql==2.1.1 apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql==2.0.1 apache-airflow-providers-odbc==2.0.1 apache-airflow-providers-mongo==2.3.0 apache-airflow-providers-opsgenie==3.0.0 snowflake-connector-python boto3==1.24.54 botocore==1.27.54 pandas==1.3.5 psycopg2-binary==2.9.3 kubernetes==23.6.0 requests==2.26.0 snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.4 mysql-connector-python==8.0.26 mysqlclient==2.1.0 opsgenie-sdk==2.1.5 pymssql==2.2.2 pymongo==3.12.3 timeago==1.0.15 billiard==3.6.4.0 apache-airflow-providers-slack  ntlm-auth==1.5.0 python-dateutil==2.8.2 pytz==2021.3 requests-ntlm==1.1.0'
```

**Error**: `cannot import name 'STATE_COLORS' from 'airflow.settings' (/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py)`

Previously it was working fine with `apache-airflow-providers-amazon==3.0.0` but this package doesn't support the fix for running multiple SQL statements for Redshift which works only on provider version 5.0.0

**From constraints for airflow 2.3.0** ,It's amazon provider==3.3.0 not 5.0.0

[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.3.0/constraints-3.7.txt#:~:text=1.1.1%0Aapache%2Dairf[…]%2Damazon%3D%3D3.3.0%0Aapache](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.3.0/constraints-3.7.txt#:%7E:text=1.1.1%0Aapache%2Dairf%5B%E2%80%A6%5D%2Damazon%3D%3D3.3.0%0Aapache)

**Log:**

```
airflow-triggerer_1  | Requirement already satisfied: Babel>=2.3 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask-Babel<3,>=1->flask-appbuilder==3.4.5->apache-airflow>=2.2.0->apache-airflow-providers-amazon==5.0.0) (2.10.1)
airflow-triggerer_1  | Requirement already satisfied: python3-openid>=2.0 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask-OpenID<2,>=1.2.5->flask-appbuilder==3.4.5->apache-airflow>=2.2.0->apache-airflow-providers-amazon==5.0.0) (3.2.0)
airflow-triggerer_1  | Requirement already satisfied: anyio==3.* in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from httpcore<0.15.0,>=0.14.5->httpx->apache-airflow>=2.2.0->apache-airflow-providers-amazon==5.0.0) (3.5.0)
airflow-triggerer_1  | Requirement already satisfied: h11<0.13,>=0.11 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from httpcore<0.15.0,>=0.14.5->httpx->apache-airflow>=2.2.0->apache-airflow-providers-amazon==5.0.0) (0.12.0)
flower_1             | cannot import name 'STATE_COLORS' from 'airflow.settings' (/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py)
flower_1             | Traceback (most recent call last):
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 595, in getimport
flower_1             |     return import_string(full_qualified_path)
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 32, in import_string
flower_1             |     module = import_module(module_path)
flower_1             |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
flower_1             |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
flower_1             |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
flower_1             |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
flower_1             |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
flower_1             |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
flower_1             |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
flower_1             |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/secrets/secrets_manager.py", line 30, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.models.connection import Connection
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator, BaseOperatorLink
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 74, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.models.mappedoperator import OperatorPartial, validate_mapping_kwargs
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/mappedoperator.py", line 63, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.models.pool import Pool
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/pool.py", line 26, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.ti_deps.dependencies_states import EXECUTION_STATES
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/ti_deps/dependencies_states.py", line 18, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.utils.state import State
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/state.py", line 22, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.settings import STATE_COLORS
flower_1             | ImportError: cannot import name 'STATE_COLORS' from 'airflow.settings' (/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py)
flower_1             |
flower_1             | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
flower_1             |
flower_1             | Traceback (most recent call last):
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.__main__ import main
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow import settings
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 35, in <module>
flower_1             |     from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1344, in <module>
flower_1             |     secrets_backend_list = initialize_secrets_backends()
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1265, in initialize_secrets_backends
flower_1             |     custom_secret_backend = get_custom_secret_backend()
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1244, in get_custom_secret_backend
flower_1             |     secrets_backend_cls = conf.getimport(section='secrets', key='backend')
flower_1             |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 599, in getimport
flower_1             |     f'The object could not be loaded. Please check "{key}" key in "{section}" section. '
flower_1             | airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: The object could not be loaded. Please check "backend" key in "secrets" section. Current value: "airflow.providers.amazon.aws.secrets.secrets_manager.SecretsManagerBackend".
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in 5.0.0. There appears to be a PR to fix it. https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/25810

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).